# How to find the maximum element of a list of lists?

Tags: python-2.7

Suppose I have a list as follows:-

```
L=[[1,2.5],[2,5.2],[3,0.5],[4,2.7]]
```

I want to find the value of L[i][0] whose L[i][1] is the maximum. In this case I want to return 2 as 5.2 is highest.

I wrote the function as:=

```
a=max(L,key=lambda x:L[x][1])
```

This show me an error "list indices must be integers, not list"

How to fix it?

Comment: How to fix: see inspectorG4dget's answer. Why: `max` takes an iterable, so in your lambda function `x` is an item of `L` (`[1,2.5]` for instance), so `L[x][1]` doesn't work. But, `x:x[1]` does what you meant and takes the item (`[2,5.2]`), so will have to take the first element of your item.

Answer (score 2):

```
import operator

In [23]: L=[[1,2.5],[2,5.2],[3,0.5],[4,2.7]]

In [24]: max(L, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]  # equivalently, key=lambda s:s[1]
Out[24]: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`max` takes a `key` argument:

```
>>> max(L, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
2
```

`x` is each element of the list in turn, so to compare based on the second element of the tuple `x`, you need to index it once as `x[1]`.